# Why can't I change the width of html buttons on class level in css?

Tags: html, css

I want three buttons to each take up 33% of the assigned space. They are grouped in a class "numbers".

When I define the width for the button tags, that works fine, but when I do it for all buttons in the class that they belong to, nothing happens.

html:

```
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="opmaak.css">
<body>
    <section class="numbers">
        <button type="button" value=1> 1</button>
        <button type="button" value=2> 2</button>
        <button type="button" value=3> 3</button><br>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

css  when I do it on button level:

```
button {
    width: 33%;
}
```

css when I try it for all buttons of that class:

```
button.numbers {
    width:33%;
}
```

Could anyone point out why that is?

```css
button.numbers {
    width: 33%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="opmaak.css">
<body>
    <section class="numbers">
        <button type="button" value=1> 1</button>
        <button type="button" value=2> 2</button>
        <button type="button" value=3> 3</button><br>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `.numbers button {...}`, also it would be good to put your  `<link...` tag into a `<head>` section

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just an issue with the CSS selector:

```
button.numbers {
    width:33%;
}
```

Should be:

```
.numbers > button {
    width:33%;
}
```

Each `button` is a *direct child* of the `.numbers` class.

The original selector `button.numbers` would only select `button` elements that had a class of `numbers` (i.e. `<button class="numbers" ...>`).

Answer (score 4):

### Explanation

HTML's `class` attribute does not inherit to children HTML tags.

Actually, only the `section` tag has set its `class="numbers"`.

### Fix

So you have to mind that for using a fitting CSS selector.

Either use

```css
.numbers > button
```

to only match direct (first order) children of `button` elements within elements of class `number`

or use

```css
.numbers button
```

to match any children of `button` elements within elements of class `number`.

Of course there are many more possibilities to specify special selection needs.

Answer (score 3):

it should be

```
.numbers button{
   width:33%;
 }
```

Comment: This is the correct approach

Comment: Your welcome. The main concept is choosing the correct selector. `.numbers button` says `select every 'button' tag that is inside an element with '.numbers' class. `.numbers > button` says `select every button tag that is DIRECT CHILD of the element with class 'numbers'`.

Answer (score 2):

```
button.numbers {
    width:33%;
}
```

This css selector means apply styles to button tag which has class as numbers. It would work on this

```
 <button class="numbers" type="button" value=1> 1</button>
```

Your button tag don't have class.

Answer (score 2):

The selector you have given specifies the with of each `button` element having the `numbers` class. Instead, you have wanted a selector that specifies each `button` children of an element having a `numbers` class:

```css
.numbers > button {
    width: 33%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="opmaak.css">
<body>
    <section class="numbers">
        <button type="button" value=1> 1</button>
        <button type="button" value=2> 2</button>
        <button type="button" value=3> 3</button><br>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```